# how to display the data Provider data in date wise order?

Tags: php, yii

I use this code.but i not get the answer.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;        
                    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday', array(
                    'criteria'=>array('condition'=>'Date orderby desc'),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
                ),
            ));
```

Comment: I tried this code.its working for me.$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday', array(
      'criteria' => array(
      'order'  => 'Date DESC',
      ),
      'pagination'=>array(
      'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
      ),
     ));

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;        
                $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday', array(
                'criteria'=>array('order'=>'Date desc'),
                'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
            ),
        ));
```

or

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->order = 'date DESC';
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday', array(
                'criteria'=>criteria,
                'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
            ),
        ));
```